# Use vim code folding markers to generate index (contents)

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc I have the lines

```
:set foldmethod=marker
:set foldmarker=SECTION:,ENDSECTION:
```

for custom code folding. In my files the comment character in the respecting language preceeds the code folding marker and they are followed by the title of the corresponding section. E.g.

```
# SECTION: First Section
some code
# SECTIION: Subsection
some more code
# ENDSECTION: 
# ENDSECTION: 

# SECTION: Second Section
some other code
# ENDSECTION:
```

This structure has all whats needed to generate a content for the file like

```
First Section
    Subsection
Second Section
```

(ideally this index has markers similar to the vim help system so I can jump to the corresponding SECTION easily; I have no idea how to achieve this). 
I can think of an easy perl script which generates this text, but I would prefere a solution based on a vim script which shows the index in a new window. Maybe there exists a solution already which does this?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your vimrc and run `:MkIdx` or `<leader>z`. You can also pass a range to the command, but the default is the whole buffer.

```
function! MkIdx() range
      let items = filter(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline), 'v:val =~ ''\C^\s*#\s\+SECTION''')
      new
      call setline(1, map(items, 'substitute(v:val, ''^\(\s*\)[^:]\+:\(.\+\)'', ''\1\2'', '''')'))
      " Mapping to jump to section:
      nnore <silent><buffer><leader>x :<C-U>call Go2Section()<CR>
endfunction

function! Go2Section()
      let section = matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*\zs.*')
      quit
      call search('\C# SECTION:\s\+'.section, 'cw')
endfunction

command! -bar -range=% MkIdx <line1>,<line2>call MkIdx()
" Mapping to build the index:
nnore <silent><leader>z :<C-U>MkIdx<CR>
```

Edit: Put index on a new buffer.

Edit 2: Don't leave an empty line.

edit 3: Allow jumping back to sections with `<leader>x`.

Comment: Looks good and seems working. Any idea how to implement indentation or jump markers?

Comment: How would you like the indentation to work? as it is it should preserve the indentation of the source. How do you expect to use the jump markers? Is the new index buffer persistent? Do you need it to work on more than one buffer?

Comment: Yes, I see the indentation in the above example would be preserved, but I would prefere to use the indentation suggested by the nested SECTION ENDSECTION structure ... but I see that this is more complicated. The jump markers would idealy bring me to the corresponding section in my main buffer if I place the curser over a word in the index buffer and press a shortcut. Realistic?

Comment: I updated the code to create the index with `<leader>z` and allow jumping back with `<leader>x`. I still don't get how you want the indentation, can you change the sample output and elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I edited the question to explain the indentation issue (only the indentation in the code sample dissappeared).  Your solution works except I had to add ! after quit in Go2Section (otherwise I get a not saved error) and the nnore command in MkIdx works only if I enter it manually in the index buffer. Not sure if this is an iterference with my other commands ...

Comment: The bang issue was because I assumed you had `set hidden` in your vimrc, my bad. I just realized that both mappings can have the same LHS, not sure what is the issue with the mapping. If you want me to modify the indentation, a pastebin would work for me.

Comment: The issue with the mapping in the function in the index buffer seems to be related to the definition of the MkIdx command in the main buffer since it works if I execute "%call MkIdx()" in the main buffer. But I dont understand how...